# Flip Back to Another View on the same view controller By click the Alert Ok Button in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

I want to flip back from one view to another view on the same view Controller by using the Alert action Button .I use below mention code but it works on UIButton Action . Please share some info

```
@IBAction func Flip(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
   UIView.transition(from: View1 , to: View2, duration: 0.3, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromLeft, completion:nil)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
let alertView = UIAlertController(title:"mainTitle", message:"mainMessage", preferredStyle: .alert)
alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "subTitle", style: .default, handler: { (alertView) in
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   UIView.transition(from: self.View1 , to: self.View2, duration: 0.3, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromLeft, completion:nil)
}
}))
self.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes i did that , i used weak property to UIView's references which loose the connection on completion .By making the property strong of these UIView's references it's working properly. Thanks